# Bulk write on ElasticSearch 2.0 NEST 2.0 throws a stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, elasticsearch, nest, nest2

I was using bulk insertion on my ElasticSearch 1.0 and NEST 1.0. Now I moved to ElasticSearch 2.0 and NEST 2.0 and the bulk insertion throws a stackoverflow (!) exception. My gut feeling is that an infinite recursion is taking place and it consumes the entire stack.

this is my POCO

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "MyDoc")]
public class MyDoc: DynamicResponse
{
    [String(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string HistoryId { get; set; }

    [String(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string FileId { get; set; }

    [Date(Store = false)]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

That's how I create the mapping:

```
elastic.Map<MyDoc>(m => m.Index(indexName).AutoMap());
```

Bulk insertion is done in two steps

First I create the descriptor:

```
        List<dynamic> dataRecordList;

        var descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();

        if (dataRecordList == null || dataRecordList.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var dataRecord in dataRecordList)
        {
            var nonClosedDataRecord = dataRecord;

            descriptor.Index<object>(record => record.Index(indexName).Type("MyDoc").Document(nonClosedDataRecord));
        }
```

Then I call the NEST `bulk()` method

```
        var bulkResponse = elastic.Bulk(d => descriptor);
```

I get the stackoverflow exception inside the foreach, when calling `descriptor.Index()`

**EDIT**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

Unfortunately no more details are available as the exception occurred on an external code (system or framework?)

Comment: @Rob here we go. Looks like there are no more details

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of the descriptor creation; in your example, the `dataRecordList` is never initialized. Have you tried serializing the bulk descriptor in isolation? Does that work?

Comment: @RussCam please don't look at this question anymore. I did a little bit of investigation and the problem boils down to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745689/nest-2-0-doesnt-persist-some-fields-into-elasticsearch-2-0

Comment: cool, feel free to close this question :)