# NEST 2.0 doesn't persist some fields into ElasticSearch 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, elasticsearch, nest, nest2

This is my document:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "MyDoc")]
public class MyDoc: Dictionary<string, object>
{
    [String(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, it inherits from `Dictionary<string, object>` so I can dinamically add fields to it (this is a requirement to make aggregation work)

Here I store the mapping:

```
client.Map<MyDoc>(m => m.Index("myindexname").AutoMap());
```

Now I create a new record and store it:

```
 var rec= new MyDoc();
 rec.Add("id", "mystuff");
 rec.text = "mytext";
 client.Index(rec, i => i.Index("myindexname"));
 client.Refresh("myindexname");
```

The record get actually stored but the text field is not persisted. Here the JSON back from ElasticSearch 2.0

```
{
"_index": "myindexname",
"_type": "MyDoc",
"_id": "AVM3B2dlrjN2fcJKmw_z",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"id": "mystuff"
}
}
```

If I remove the base class from `MyDoc` the `text` field is stored correctly but obviously the dictionary content is not (I also need to remove the `.Add()` bit as the document doesn't inherit from a `Dictionary`).

How to store both the `text` field and the dictionary content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i wrote wrong suggestion in my previous post so i deleted it.
I think issues is actually in serialization since your base class is  Dictionary

I would do two things first try to serialize your object to see output string i am pretty sure that text is ignored.

Second i would change class to following

```
public class MyDoc : Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        public string text
        {
            get
            {
                object mytext;
                return TryGetValue("text", out mytext) ? mytext.ToString() : null;
            }
            set { this.Add("text", value);}
        }
    }
```

PS. As i thought issue is on c# side since you inherit from dictionary,

```
var rec = new MyDoc();
rec.Add("id", "mystuff");
rec.text = "mytext";
//Text2 is property         public string text2 { get; set; }
rec.text2 = "mytext2";
var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rec); //{"id":"mystuff","text":"mytext"}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a wrapper which stores the text using the dictionary. It's fine ok but I was looking for the reason why the normal fields are not stored. It must be possible to store both the normal fields and the dictionary content

Comment: Because you are inheriting from dictionary.

Comment: Ok but why if I inherits from dictionary the other fields are ignored. Is this a basic rule hardwired into elasticsearch or what?

Comment: Its releated to C# it has nothing to do with elasticsearch since c#, serialize and then send to ES as a string.

Comment: Try to do the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893614/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-as-part-of-its-parent-object-using-json-net I am not sure if it would work since i did not tired that

Comment: This is default JSON.Net behaviour; if the type being serialized implements `IEnumerable<T>`, then it will be serialized as a collection and hence other properties that are not iterated/enumerated will not be included. You could write a custom json converter to handle this too, but this answer ensures that an item with the key `text` cannot be added to the dictionary in addition to the `text` property so is a good way to handle this